# how do i define this object in order to add event listeners to my form? unsure of what to do

Tags: javascript, html, forms, object, undefined

i need to define the ShapeLink object in order to allow me to add an event listener to the form that checks for "submit" events to the initForm function. however, when i make one, it says that the ShapeLink object is undefined and i am having trouble defining it

```
<body>
<form>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <label for="shapeSelect">Shape:</label>
    <select name="" id="shapeSelect">
        <option value="">pick a shape</option>
        <option value="square">Square</option>
        <option value="circle">Circle</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="outputText"></div>
<svg width=100 height=100></svg>
<script>
    ShapeLink.initForm(document.querySelector("form"));
</script>
</body>
```

but i need to add it in my javascript and i am unsure of what goes where and why

```
let ShapeLink = (function(){
//code here!

return {
    initForm: function(frm){
        //code here!

    }
}
})()
```

all of my code must be in my javascript. what do i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you are attaching event listener but your code seems to be working:

```js
let ShapeLink = (function(){
//code here!

return {
    initForm: function(frm){
        //code here!
        frm.addEventListener('submit',function(){
          alert('form submitting');
        })
    }
}
})()

ShapeLink.initForm(document.querySelector("form"));
```

```html
<form>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <label for="shapeSelect">Shape:</label>
    <select name="" id="shapeSelect">
        <option value="">pick a shape</option>
        <option value="square">Square</option>
        <option value="circle">Circle</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="outputText"></div>
<svg width=100 height=100></svg>
```

Comment: now i am trying to use template literals to display the name and selected elements in the outputText Div but they are also undefined, what do i do?

Comment: @J.Morris, can you please update the question with the template?